# Is there way to keep queue data in memory in java GUI program

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I'm writing a program to simulate a waiting queue for campus students this program users a linked list to do the queue and I used a button click event to execute the code.

It works only once every time add it only holds one student I think it because the list gets cleared after the button click event. I just want know is there a way to keep the list active till I terminate the main program.

My Code Below:

```
private void addStd1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
            Queue stdQue = new LinkedList(); <-- Create the queue

            String stName = addStdName.getText();

            int sId;
            int stdQuality;


            if(!stName.isEmpty()){
// Generate a random number as Id
            RanNum tempId = new RanNum();
            sId = tempId.genNum();

// Generate a random number as a quality number to be matched later with the apartment
            RanNum tempQuality = new RanNum();
            stdQuality = tempQuality.genNum();

            //StdDetails sTn = new StdDetails(sId, stName, stdQuality);
            stdQue.add(sId);
            stdQue.add(stdQuality);
            stdQue.add(stName);

            Object atTop = stdQue.element().toString();

            if (!stdQue.isEmpty()){
                crntTop.setText("Current top of the list: " + atTop + "  Student ID: " + sId);
                addStdName.setText("");

            }else{
                crntTop.setText("Queue list is empty.");
            }
           }else{
                crntTop.setText("Please, enter student name.");
            }

            if(!stdQue.isEmpty()){
                for(Object name : stdQue){
                lstQue.setText(name.toString());   
                }            
            }
        }
```

The above code functions with out error I just want to find out to keep the queue live until the user terminate the main program.

I think this can be archived in a CLI program using a while loop but this is a GUI program I don;t know how to do that in a this format.

**UPDATE**
I made changes according to @learninloop when I do that I get an error "Cannot Find Symbol:method addStd1ActionPerformed(evt)". Also like to inform you that I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 as my java IDE.

```
addStd1.setText("Add Student");
addStd1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {addStd1ActionPerformed(evt);}
```

And the changed main code is below:

```
class stdQueCls{
        Queue stdQue;               
        public stdQueCls(){
            stdQue = new LinkedList();
        }
    private void addStd1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        /*AddStdFrm newWindow = null;
        newWindow = new AddStdFrm();
        newWindow.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);*/
        String stName = addStdName.getText();


        if(!stName.isEmpty()){

        //StdDetails sTn = new StdDetails(sId, stName, stdQuality);

           int sId;
           int stdQuality;

           RanNum tempId = new RanNum();
           sId = tempId.genNum();

           RanNum tempQuality = new RanNum();
           stdQuality = tempQuality.genNum();

           stdQue.add(sId);
           stdQue.add(stdQuality);
           stdQue.add(stName);

        Object atTop = stdQue.element().toString();

        if (!stdQue.isEmpty()){
            crntTop.setText("Current top of the list: " + atTop + "  Student ID: " + sId);
            addStdName.setText("");

        }else{
            crntTop.setText("Queue list is empty.");
        }
       }else{
            crntTop.setText("Please, enter student name.");
        }

        if(!stdQue.isEmpty()){
            for(Object name : stdQue){
            lstQue.setText(name.toString());   
            }            
        }        
    }                                       
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I changed the code and put my linked list in to a class and moved it totally out of the button click event. So the new code as follows,

```
    class stdQueCls{
        Queue stdQue;               
        public stdQueCls(){
            stdQue = new LinkedList();

            if (!stdQue.isEmpty()){
            for(Object all : stdQue){
            lstQue.setText(all.toString());   
            }
           }
        }
    }
    public void addStd1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        /*AddStdFrm newWindow = null;
        newWindow = new AddStdFrm();
        newWindow.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);*/
        String stName = addStdName.getText();


        if(!stName.isEmpty()){

        //StdDetails sTn = new StdDetails(sId, stName, stdQuality);
            stdQueCls stdQue1 = new stdQueCls();
           int sId;
           int stdQuality;

           RanNum tempId = new RanNum();
           sId = tempId.genNum();

           RanNum tempQuality = new RanNum();
           stdQuality = tempQuality.genNum();

           stdQue1.stdQue.add(sId);
           stdQue1.stdQue.add(stdQuality);
           stdQue1.stdQue.add(stName);

   Object atTop = stdQue1.stdQue.element().toString();

  if (!stdQue1.stdQue.isEmpty()){
   crntTop.setText("Current top of the list: " + atTop + "  Student ID: " + sId);
   addStdName.setText("");

  }else{
   crntTop.setText("Queue list is empty.");
  }
  }else{
   crntTop.setText("Please, enter student name.");
 }
}
```

Now as you see in my class I want to display what ever in the queue in a text area named queLst as you can see I have used a for loop to do it but my issue is it's not displaying the list in the text area and the other thing when it's placed inside the button click event it works but adds what ever I enter at that point can some show me a way or give an idea to how to archive this.

**UPDATE**
I did some changes to the above code now it working but I don't if I'm doing this wrong one things is when I retrieve the inserted data from the queue it not what I expect to see and I think still my queue linked list is not getting populated.

Can some one please have a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing is write or wrong.

```
  class stdQueCls{
        Queue<stdDetailGroup> stdQue;               
        public stdQueCls(){
            stdQue = new LinkedList<stdDetailGroup>();
            //lstQue.setText(stdQue.toString());
        }
    }

    class stdDetailGroup{
           String stdId;
           String stQuality;
           String stdName;
     public stdDetailGroup(String a, String b, String c){
        stdId = a;
        stQuality = b;
        stdName = c;
    }
    }
    public void addStd1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        /*AddStdFrm newWindow = null;
        newWindow = new AddStdFrm();
        newWindow.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);*/

        String stName = addStdName.getText();


        if(!stName.isEmpty()){

        //StdDetails sTn = new StdDetails(sId, stName, stdQuality);
           stdQueCls stdQue1 = new stdQueCls();

           int stdQualityInt;
           int sIdInt;
           String sId;
           String stdQuality;

           RanNum tempId = new RanNum();
           sIdInt = tempId.genNum();
           sId = Integer.toString(sIdInt);

           RanNum tempQuality = new RanNum();
           stdQualityInt = tempQuality.genNum();
           stdQuality = Integer.toString(stdQualityInt);

           stdDetailGroup stdDetailsAdd = new stdDetailGroup(sId, stdQuality, stName);
           stdQue1.stdQue.add(stdDetailsAdd);

           Object atTop = stdQue1.stdQue.toString();

        if (!stdQue1.stdQue.isEmpty()){
            crntTop.setText("Current top of the list: " + atTop + "  Student ID: " + sId);
            addStdName.setText("");

        }else{
            crntTop.setText("Queue list is empty.");
        }
       }else{
            crntTop.setText("Please, enter student name.");
        }

    }                                       

    private void shwQue1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        stdQueCls stdQue2 = new stdQueCls();

        lstQue.setText(stdQue2.stdQue.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating the linkedlist object `stdQue` inside the action performed event of button, the object is getting created and reinitialized every time the button is clicked. To make the data persistent, please take the object creation outside the button click event.

Assuming the class name as `StudentManager`, you can create the object inside the constructor:

```
class StudentManager {
   Queue stdQue;
   public StudentManager() {
      stdQue = new LinkedList(); <-- Create the queue
   }
   private void addStd1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
   {
      .
      .
      stdQue.add(sId);
      stdQue.add(stdQuality);
      stdQue.add(stName);
      .
      .
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I'm still learning java and some times my question might not be up to standards thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I get "Cannot Find Symbol:method addStd1ActionPerformed(evt)"

addStd1.setText("Add Student");
addStd1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {addStd1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }

Tha the area which I get the error.

Comment: @Jack You have taken the method `addStd1ActionPerformed` outside of `stdQueCls` class. Just verify the opening and closing brackets once.

Comment: yes I did took the 'code' addStd1ActionPerformed 'code' method out of the 'code'stdQueCls'code' because when I put it in there it started give an error in the action listener I've mentioned it as an update to this post. So that's why I moved it out and created a separate method for it.